# How to fix my problem with 'nextLine()' in my input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I can understand why `nextLine()` doesnt work.

If I change `nextLine()` with `next()` my input doest take all the phrase

```
 case 7:
        System.out.println("Press 1 to post on your wall \nPress 2 to post on a friend's wall");
        int b=scan.nextInt();
        if(b==1){
            System.out.println("What do you want to post?");
            String pm=scan.nextLine();

            Message ms= new Message(loginUser.getUsername(),loginUser.getUsername() +" :"+ pm.toString());
            message.add(ms);
        }
        if(b==2){
            System.out.println("Whose wall do you want to post? (Write his/her username)");
            String ph=scan.next();

            for(int n = 0;  n< users.size(); n++)
            {
                if(!loginUser.getUsername().equals(ph) 
                        && users.get(n).getUsername().equals(ph)){
                    System.out.println("What do you want to post?");
                    String postIt=scan.nextLine();
                    Message me= new Message( ph,ph +" : "+loginUser.getUsername() +" : " + postIt.toString() );
                    message.add(me);
                }
            }
        } 
        luna=false;
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call to `scan.nextLine()` after you call `scan.nextInt();` and not use the value from it:

```
int b=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); //Add this line
```

This is because `nextInt()` does not consume the line terminator that is used in `nextLine()` to determine the end of the line and the extra call to `nextLine()` will consume it for you correctly.

Basically before you were giving it the value `2` for example, the `nextInt()` will take the `2`, then `nextLine()` will take everything after the `2` on THAT line, which would be nothing.

This will always need to be done if you are mixing the use of `next` or `nextInt` with `nextLine`.